# Intersection of a circle and a triangle

Tags: geometry

If we have a point $(0,6)$ which is the vertex of an equilateral triangle the distance of whose all vertices are equal from origin.Draw a circle of radius 3 centered at $(0,1)$.How many number of maximum intersection of circle and triangle?

I don't know how to solve because i am week in geometry, from picture i find it may be 3 or 4,but i am not sure.Please give me some direction to solve this.

Comment: Yes i edit the question that what i have tried

Comment: No,i don't know.

Comment: Eyeballing it, to me there is either $2$ or $4$ intersections.

Comment: I 'think' I came up with the solution algebraically. I haven't been on here that long, are we allowed to give a partial solution and then a link to another question on Math.SE on how to finish where I leave off? Is that too cumbersome? I find that the lack of effort from the asker would suggest I don't need to do all the work for him/her.

Comment: Then please give some hint,iwill try myself.

Comment: @Vincent The coordinates of the vertices aren't actually what's important here. Once you realize that the given vertex is at the top of the circle, you know what the orientation of the triangle is. And since it's equilateral, the slopes of the slanted sides will be $\pm\sqrt{3}$. You also know the y-intercept for these lines, so...

Comment: Hmm. The given vertex is at $(0,6)$ and the circle is centered at $(0,1)$ with $r=3$. Doesn't that make the the top of the circle at $(0,4)$ and not at the top vertex?

Comment: @Vincent Not that circle. The vertices of the triangle are equidistant to the origin. The distance between vertex $(0,6)$ and the origin is $6$. Hence all three vertices lie on the circle of radius $6$ centered at the origin. Vertex $(0,6)$ is at the top of this circle.

Comment: Ahh, I understand that part now.

Comment: @vincent the vertices $(0,6),(-3\sqrt{2},-3\sqrt{2}),(3\sqrt{2},-3\sqrt{2})$ do not make equilateral triangle because the disance between $(0,6) and (-3\sqrt{2},-3\sqrt{2})$ and distance between $(-3\sqrt{2},-3\sqrt{2}) and (3\sqrt{2},-3\sqrt{2}) $ are different.

Comment: The points for the vertices I gave before were wrong. Yah, Rizwan, I noticed I mistook a triangle for a right triangle when it wasn't. But as David said, the other vertices don't matter.

Comment: @RizwanAhmed It might be helpful if you review the basic facts about equilateral triangles here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=equilateral+triangle.

Comment: yes it is helpful @DavidH by using the vertices it is clear that there are 4 intersection.Since i need maximum number of intersections so i think it is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the fastest or most sophisticated method, but I "**think**" it works. It is an algebraic approach to solving this type of problem. A more clever person than I can attest one way or the other.

First recognize that the slope of an equilateral triangle is $\pm\sqrt{3}$. From here, we can find the equation of the line that is a side of the triangle. Either one will work as whatever result we get for the number of intersection points for one side will be equal to the other. Thus, we can just double our answer.

Equation of a line $y=mx+b$, where $m=\pm\sqrt{3}$ (we will choose $+\sqrt{3}$), and $b=6$. Thus, we get:
$$y=\sqrt{3}x+6$$

What we are ultimately looking for is the number of intersection points between our line and the circle. The equation of a cicle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$. Where we have $a=0$, $b=1$ and $r=3$. Giving us:

$$x^2+(y-1)^2=9$$

Substitute, $y=\sqrt{3}x+6$ into $x^2+(y-1)^2=9$. After doing a little algebra we get:

$$4x^2+10\sqrt{3}x+16=0$$

Which is a quadratic with $a=4$, $b=10\sqrt{3}$ and $c=16$.

Using the discriminant of the quadratic:

If $b^2-4ac<0$, there are no points of intersection.

If $b^2-4ac=0$, the line is tangent to the circle and therefore has one point of intersection.

If $b^2-4ac\gt 0$, there are two points of intersection.

$$(10\sqrt{3})^2-4(4)(16)=44$$

Thus, each line intersects the circle at two points giving us $4$ total points of intersection.

Comment: You made a mistake somewhere. There are four points of intersection. Here's two of them: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dsqrt%283%29*x%2B6%2C+x^2%2B%28y-1%29^2%3D9

Comment: I typed that up with a fussy baby on my lap so you may be right. Let's see here.

Comment: What were your other two points of intersection? In my solution I didn't consider the base of the triangle. I'm checking that now to see if there are points of intersection.

Comment: Same as the first two points, only reflected through the y-axis. And as to your previous question, your method is sound but algebra is off. The quadratic you should get is $4x^2+10\sqrt{3}x+16=0$.

Comment: @Vincent yor quadratic equation after sustitution should be $4x^2+10\sqrt{3}x+16=0$, which has two real roots.

Comment: Yah. I am correcting it now. I forgot to take $-1$ into account when I substituted the $y$ in.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for this method, now we can see that there are 4 intersection points.

Comment: Also thanks to @DavidH

Comment: And that is why you don't answer questions with a baby on your lap. =)

Comment: @Vincent you can also consult with your baby.